# Titanium , validate an iOS App with a name that contain -> &

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

App developed with titanium

I have to publish an app called **Pizze&Altro**

The problem lies in the **&** contained in the name of the app

The file tiapp.xml gave me error, then I put the name like this: 
[image] (problem 1 solved)

However, during the validation of the app with xCode I find myself in front of this error (problem 2)

[image]

i tried this solution : https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/147989/invalid-url-scheme-when-validating-app , I copied the Info.plist file in the directory of the app by editing this section like this:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>--.--.--</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>Pizze&amp;Altro</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

or

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>--.--.--</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>Pizze&Altro</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

but I keep finding myself in front of the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this particular issue in one of my apps by using localization:

**Step 1**: In your tiapp.xml, use a name without any special symbols:

```
<name>Pizze Altro</name>
```

**Step 2**: Create `i18n/en/app.xml` with the following contents (note i18n should be in the same directory as Resources; it shouldn't be inside Resources itself):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="appname">Pizze&Altro</string>
</resources>
```

**Step 3**: Clean the project, then try publishing again.

See this blog post from Appcelerator for the same information, plus information on how to do the same for Android (you didn't ask or tag Android, so I haven't included that information directly):
http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/02/internationalization-of-app-names/

Comment: thanks for the reply. only for iOS yes . can i use only 1 file app.xml for all languages ? (for example the only i18n/en/app.xml file?)

Comment: Yes, you can. If, for example, the device is set to use Spanish, but only English is available for your app, then it uses English. Feel free to test this out in the simulator by using the Settings app to change the selected language. You'll see that your app will still work.

Comment: yes, I have done some test and it works perfectly, thanks a lot! Now I just hope there are no problems with the validation of the app, but I do not think